# How to connect to twitter with Oauth? (requesting easy code example)

Tags: android, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to understand the multiple examples of how to connect to twitter with Android, but all of them are too hard for me. I'm also reading the documentation but it is not helping me a lot.

Someone have's a link or a easy code example to do it?

Sorry for ask for a code example but i'm getting absolutly stuck on this...

Comment: there is some [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples) on the twitter developer documentation. I don't know about java but it may be a good start

Answer (score 0):

It indeed took me a while to understand how it worked.

How oauth works:
http://term.ie/oauth/example/
Example in php:
http://social-php.googlecode.com/files/social-php_0.1.tar.gz
For me the examples at linkedin helped me to understand
https://developer.linkedin.com/apis

Comment: but i need examples and explanations for android, not for php, btw i will check your links

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the [oauth-signpost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/) library.  It is compatible with Android, and has samples for connecting with [Twitter](https://github.com/kaeppler/signpost-examples/tree/master/OAuthTwitterExample), [Google](https://github.com/kaeppler/signpost-examples/tree/master/OAuthGoogleExample), etc.

Answer (score 0):

see this link. i hope this example helps u.
     [LINK](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/tag/jtwitter-android-api/)